# How to scrape for multiple quotes from Yahoo using Beautiflul Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape multiple quotes from Yahoo Finance not just one at a time.  All I'm interested in is getting the Stock Price.  I have scoured the html that Beautiful Soup provides but I cannot find the correct tag to use to get the prices nor are the prices even in the HTML.  Would anyone please give me the Beautifulsoup command to use to get the table of stocks?
Here is the URL I'm using to test.  https://finance.yahoo.com/quotes/AAPL,WYNN,PCB,AMZN,USAK/view/v1

Comment: probably page uses JavaScript to add elements but `requests`/`Beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript and you may need `Selenium` to control web browser which can run JavaScript. BUT first you should check if yahoo finance doesn't have API and there should be special Python module to get data without scraping.

Comment: see modules [yahoo-finance](https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/) and [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have previously tried both yahoo-finanace and yfinance but they do not provide a way (at least I haven't found one) to simply get a current price for multiple symbols.  And doing a call one symbol at a time takes too long.  That is why I thought I would try scraping. If it cannot be done so be it and thank you again for replying.

Comment: [yahoofinancials](https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials) can do `YahooFinancials(['AAPL','WYNN','PCB','AMZN','USAK'])` but it need some time - probably it gets every data in separated request. When I use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to check requests used on page in your link then I see it also send separated request for every symbol. But maybe it has access to faster computers https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/spark?symbols=AAPL&range=1d&interval=5m&indicators=close&includeTimestamps=false&includePrePost=false&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance

Comment: using data directly from https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/spark?symbols=AAPL&range=1d&interval=5m&indicators=close&includeTimestamps=false&includePrePost=false&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance should be faster then scraping page - but maybe it may need some other information (ie. cookies) like in real web browser.

Answer (score 0):

When I use `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` for page

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/quotes/AAPL,WYNN,PCB,AMZN,USAK/view/v1
```

then I see it sends separated requests for every symbol and it uses urls like

```
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/spark?symbols=AAPL&range=1d&interval=5m&indicators=close&includeTimestamps=false&includePrePost=false&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com&.tsrc=finance
```

The same with python works fast.

I'm only afraid it may need some other elements - ie. cookies - to prevent blocking after many requests.

```
import requests

for symbol in ['AAPL', 'WYNN', 'PCB', 'AMZN', 'USAK']:
    params = {
        'symbols': symbol,
        'range': '1d',
        'interval': '5m',
        'indicators': 'close',
        'includeTimestamps': 'false',
        'includePrePost': 'false',
        'corsDomain': 'finance.yahoo.com',
        '.tsrc': 'finance'
    }

    url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/spark'

    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    data = r.json()

    print('---', symbol, '---')
    print(data['spark']['result'][0]['response'][0]['indicators']['quote'][0]['close'])
```